# watchOS 4 contentFrame for multiple interface controller pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I have an Apple Watch app which consists of a main page that has a table view. When selecting a row, I am presenting some InterfaceControllers as pages:

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"Controller1", @"Controller2", @"Controller3", @"Controller4 etc"] contexts:@[contexts....]];
```

Strangely, when displaying only one InterfaceController it shows up correctly, the interface starts right below the status bar.

However, when I present multiple pages as in the code above, the contentFrame shrinks and there is a black space between the status bar on top and the actual content.

What is that for and how can I remove it?

Single Page:

[image: single page]

Multiple pages:

[image]